# Free software to track movies I'm watching

Tags: gratis, database

I am looking for either a web app or installable program that will track the
movies I have watched.

I have found a few online but I would like one that also tracks how many times I
have watched each movie, as I like to rewatch many of my movies.

I would also like to be able to easily sort the data, for example sorting by
"last watched" or sorting by number of views.

Other requirements

- if it is an installable program, must work with Windows
- no answers saying "use a spreadsheet"
- no answers saying "make your own"
- no Windows Media Player (does not support MKV)
- no Banshee (Windows version is out of date)

Edit: a moderator deleted my answer even though it fits my needs. 
http://trakt.tv is a site that works for me.

Comment: A spreadsheet program allows you to do all of this easily. If you are looking for more features than what a spreadsheet program provides, please state these other wanted features explicitly. For instance, should the app be integrated to a movies database so that you don't have to type the full name of the movie? Do you want it to show movie poster thumbnails automatically retrieved from the Internet?

Comment: I Think what you Search is an MediaCenter Like XBmc :D
Xbmc Tracks an Movie or Show you look as Watched .
But i cant remember if he saves how often you watched the movie :(

Comment: What's your preferred movie player? I'd guess any such app would likely need to tie into that

Comment: If you're not opposed to codecs, the Combined Community Codec Pack will allows DirectShow based media players play MKV (yes Windows Media Player). http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Should the program be able to track the movies automatically, or basically you just need a dedicated front-end to a database which gets populated manually? What kind of information you'd like to track about the movie? Is the title sufficient? Do you need to retrieve extra data from services such as [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/)?

Comment: From various clues in the text of the question, I figure you want the program to also *play* the movies, but this is very implicit and not mentioned anywhere. To improve your question, it would be nice to actually mention that you want the program to play the movies, because "a (...) program that will track the movies I have watched" really does sound like you just want the tracking (possibly by manual input of movie titles).

Comment: Your answer was deleted by a moderator because it was pretty much a link only answer. All answers (even if answered by the OP) must meet [these guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/133), I would consider editing your answer and then ask for an undeletion.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Banshee. Here is the link http://banshee.fm/, this will do all the things you want automatically as long as you import your moves to banshee. It will track how many times you watch something or if you have ever watched it. Banshee does a lot of thing from music to videos. It will also play your mkv files ( I just played an mkv move on mine)
It's cross platform so it will work on whatever operating system you have.

Comment: The fact that it has not updated in 2 years may mean that it is stable and needs nothing new. Again, you need better requirements in your question to give us a better chance of helping you.

Answer (score 0):

[Smovault](http://smovault.blogspot.com/p/features.html) is a software that might work for you.
It is free for personal use.
It uses [TMDb](https://www.themoviedb.org/) to download movie data like cast, crew, posters, etc and also provides movie recommendations based on your taste.
Unfortunately it currently does not have some of the features requested by you, but are planned for the next release.

[DISCLOSURE] - I am the developer of Smovault.